# Travis CI deploy: invalid option "--secret_access_key="

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, travis-ci

I am building a Java web app with Travis CI and trying to deploy it to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance. The build goes well:

```
The command "mvn test -B" exited with 0.
```

... but the deploy fails and says:

```
Fetching: dpl-1.8.31.gem (100%)
Successfully installed dpl-1.8.31
1 gem installed

invalid option "--secret_access_key="
failed to deploy
```

my `.travis.yml` file seems to be valid and I have stored in it my *encrypted* secret access key for AWS using the travis CLI tool:

```
travis encrypt secret_access_key="< my secret access key >"
```

So why can't I deploy to AWS? why does Travis tell me `invalid option "--secret_access_key="`?

I have checked [the Travis `dpl` docs](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl#elastic-beanstalk) for Elastic Beanstalk and they say the option for the key should be `--secret-access-key=...`, with **dashes** (instead of **underscores** like in `invalid option "--secret_access_key="` from my Travis log).

How can I deploy my application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also encountered this issue and it was because the encrypted environment variable I used for `secret_access_key:` was spelled incorrectly. Most likely the value used here is wrong or non-existent and will produce this error.

`secret_access_key: $ENCRYPTED_VAR_SPELLED_WRONG`

Comment: Yes, I remember I solved the issue by encrypting the fully-qualified name of the key (`deploy.secret_access_key` if I remember well).